# XML parser to Android

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, soap

How can I parse xml response with inner tags like this:
The parsers which I know of can't parse this style, maybe somebody knows a quick way to solve it.

```
"xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset'" +
                "xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema'>" +
                "<rs:data ItemCount=\"1\">" +
                "<z:row ows_Attachments='0' ows_LinkTitle='item1' ows_Status='Not Started' ows_Priority='(2) Normal' ows_Predecessors='' " +
                "ows__ModerationStatus='0' ows__Level='1' ows_Title='item1' ows_ID='1' ows_UniqueId='1;#{BD66E621-A09E-43C0-B1F7-C640E93A67AD}' " +
                "ows_owshiddenversion='1' ows_FSObjType='1;#0' ows_Created_x0020_Date='1;#2012-03-01 16:19:50' ows_Created='2012-03-01 16:19:50'" +
                "ows_FileLeafRef='1;#1_.000' ows_PermMask='0x7fffffffffffffff' ows_Modified='2012-03-01 16:19:50' ows_FileRef='1;#Lists/TestList/1_.000' />" +
                "</rs:data>"
```

Comment: Are your check your responce is valid?

Comment: yes, its a raw quary from sharepoint server. All promlems in this row <z:row..> the parser skips data in this tag

Comment: Don't say "the parsers which I know can't parse this style". Tell us exactly what you did and exactly how it failed.

Comment: sorry.. when I tell this, I meant that parser skips inner attributes like as ows_Attachments and other. I understood my mistake